# How to handle KeyEvents in a DataGridViewCell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a `Keydown` Event of a `DataGridViewCell`?
What I'm trying to do is when a user is typing in a particular cell,  he can press F1 for help of that particular column. And some Form will popup...

What event it is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fea2b675-5ed4-4e61-b3ec-3abe5d9e8d61) code in a forum, and it works.

```cs
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
   tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);    
   e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress);
}
    
private void dataGridViewTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   //when i press enter,bellow code never run?
   if (e.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Enter)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("You press Enter");
   }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  The KeyDown, KeyUp and KeyPressed events would not fire when the enter key was pressed (however they would for character keys).  What I had to use was the PreviewKeyDown event for the DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl object to be able to capture the Enter key.

Answer (score 5):

`DataGridViewCell` doesn’t have any events, but you can listen for the `KeyDown` event on the `DataGridView` itself and then look at which cell is selected:

```
public void dataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        var selectedCell = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0];
        // do something with selectedCell...
    }
}
```

Comment: Keyboard events from editing controls won't be fired for the DGV, the above code doesn't work to handle key events in edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

When the user types into a cell it is actually typing into the control that is placed inside the cell for editing purposes. For example, a string column type will actually create a TextBox for use inside the cell for the user to input against. So you need to actually hook into the KeyDown event of the TextBox that is placed inside the cell when editing takes place.

Answer (score 2):

another solution is

```
private void grdDetalle_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Sólo queremos esta funcionalidad para determinadas columnas Clave y Nombre
        if ((grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colClaveArticulo") ||
            (grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colNombre"))
        {
            /// Workarround para que estando editando en las columnas del grid Clave y Nombre
            /// podamos detectar cuando se dio F4 para lanzar el dialogo de busqueda del
            /// articulo.
            e.Control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyDown);
            e.Control.Leave += new EventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_Leave);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridViewTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colClaveArticulo") ||
           (grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colNombre"))
        {
            try
            {
                (sender as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl).KeyDown -= 
                   new KeyEventHandler(dataGridViewTextBox_KeyDown);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridViewTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // F4 Pressed
        if ((grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colClaveArticulo") ||
           (grdDetalle.Columns[grdDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "colNombre"))
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4) // 115
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oprimieron F4");
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest modifying your code with English variable names and comments so people can more easily understand what you're doing.

Comment: I agree with this solution more since you provide ways to pick specific columns

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I believe I have improved upon the top voted answer.

```
    IDataGridViewEditingControl _iDataGridViewEditingControl;
    private void SlotTimesDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_iDataGridViewEditingControl is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl iDataGridViewEditingControl = _iDataGridViewEditingControl as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            iDataGridViewEditingControl.KeyPress -= SlotTimesDGV_EditingControlShowing_KeyPress;
        }
        if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl iDataGridViewEditingControl = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            iDataGridViewEditingControl.KeyPress += SlotTimesDGV_EditingControlShowing_KeyPress;
            _iDataGridViewEditingControl = iDataGridViewEditingControl;
        }
    }

    private void SlotTimesDGV_EditingControlShowing_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }
```

By having an instance variable of the IDataGridViewEditingControl, you can remove the KeyPress event that would result in duplicate calls when moving around cells and your event is not limited to only one type of cell.

Answer (score 0):

This code did work for me.

```
Form.KeyPreview = true;
```

Description in Microsoft Docs: "...(KeyPreview) sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.".

Answer (score 0):

overriding the virtual function ProcessCmdKey for class Form worked for me.

Return true on ProcessCmdKey to prevent further handling of the keypress.
the overrided function to catches all of the key actions

Ex:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) //overridden virtual function
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab) //check to make sure it is the key I am interested in
    { 
        if (this.dataGridViewKeys.ContainsFocus) //make sure it is on the control, or any child controls, of the one I am interested in
        {
            this.dataGridViewKeys.EndEdit(); //do whatever action you want here
            if (this.dataGridViewKeys.CurrentRow.IsNewRow && this.dataGridViewKeys.Rows.Count > 1)
                this.dataGridViewKeys.CurrentCell = this.dataGridViewKeys.Rows[this.dataGridViewKeys.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2];
            this.txtNoteData.Focus();
            return true;  //I return true to prevent further handling of the keypress
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData); //return this for keys you do not want to intercept
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697966/14177529):

In your solution you shouldn't forget to unlistern to the event

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  tb.KeyUp -= Tb_KeyUp;
}
```

And in my solution i subscribed to KeyUp, not KeyDown, because i need to replace value of editing cell

```cs
DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb { get; set; }

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
    CellEditingTB.KeyUp += Tb_KeyUp;
}

private void Tb_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (tb != null)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
        {
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).