# how to assign hot key for datagridview combobox column?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

i have grid view have combobox column ["column2"]

```
     if (keyData == (Keys.F11))
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
                    {

   //here i want to change index automatically  using hot key  (keyboard short cut )
                    }
                    return true;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697517/how-to-handle-keyevents-in-a-datagridviewcell

Comment: problem in focus that cell and dropped down it  :S

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly assign `ShortcutKey` to a individual cell. Handle the `KeyPress` event of `DataGridView` for key combinations. In the event handler, put the below code

```
void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.E))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[ColumnIndex];
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }
}
```

if any cell is already in edit mode then the editing control would get the `KeyPress` events not the `DataGridView`. If you want to overcome that you have to subclass the existing DataGridView control and override its `ProcessCmdKey` function. See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284370/datagridview-keydown-event-not-working-in-c-sharp/4285099#4285099) SO question for that.

To change the selected index of the editing combo, subscribe the `EditingControlShowing` event and in the event handler change the `combobox` index.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox control = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (control !=null)
    {
       // set the selected index of the combo here.
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanna change index of this column by shortcut key !

Comment: @KOKO Sorry I can't understand your intention... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: not only select combobox cell i wanna to change index of cell