# MenuItem shortcut key binding prevents default handle

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to write a DataGridView with a context menu. I have a menu item in the context menu with the delete key as its shortcut which removes a row from the DataGridView only when the user isn't editing a cell and asking for user's confirmation before removing the row.

The problem is when the user is editing a cell and presses the delete key the next character of the selected cell content is not deleted. I guess this is because of the shortcut binding but I don't know how to fix this.

If I remove the shortcut I works correctly but the dialog for user's confimation doesn't appear.

This is how my menu item handler looks now.

```
void miEliminar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    if (!this.ReadOnly && !this.IsCurrentCellInEditMode)
        this.RemoveSelectedRows();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Shortcut key event fires and binds with its handler. See one of the comments in the [MSDN page on Menu ShortCut Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeys(v=vs.100).aspx) Have you tried using the keypress event Check this [handle keyevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697517/how-to-handle-keyevents-in-a-datagridviewcell) out